# Android Q Beta - Strongly-Typed Permission

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-manifest, android-permissions

I am testing my apps with `Android Q SDK` and after refactoring some things to be compatible on the new `API`, stucked in requesting some permissions.

In the app manifest file i have declared for e.x

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

When compiling with `Android Q SDK` it says that this is deprecated.
After looking in documentation they say :

> This constant was deprecated in API level Q. replaced by new
>   strongly-typed permission groups in Q.

So, what is `strongly-typed permission` and how to declare in proper way and request from app code (java or kotlin)? Or they doesn't have provided any documentation for this yet and we should wait in following news ?

P.s : `android.permission-group.STORAGE` is deprecated too.

Comment: Presumably, they are referring to `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`, `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`, and `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`, as part of [the scoped storage stuff](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/scoped-storage). In Q Beta 1, you needed to hold a role to obtain those permissions (e.g., `ROLE_GALLERY`). However, the documentation on roles has been removed, and I have not had an opportunity to test to see whether these are normal permissions, `dangerous` ones that we request at runtime, or if we still need to use the undocumented roles stuff.

Comment: @CommonsWare, i think they doesn't have added yet documentation for this and how to use in proper way. In my case i'm using two permissions that it says to be deprecated : 
`android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Comment: @CommonsWare, also i have tested in both `Q Beta 1` and `Q Beta 2`

Comment: "i think they doesn't have added yet documentation for this and how to use in proper way" -- yes, it is a mess. Here is the first of five blog posts where I describe how Q Beta 1 worked: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/03/25/death-external-storage-what-now.html. I will need to make changes to adapt to Q Beta 2.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [myself](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/04/04/random-musings-q-beta-2.html):

> There are now three "strongly-typed"
>   permissions for read access to external storage:
>
> - `READ_MEDIA_AUDIO`
> - `READ_MEDIA_IMAGES`
> - `READ_MEDIA_VIDEO`
>
> These are `dangerous` permissions, so you will handle them the same as `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.
>   If your app has `targetSdkVersion` set to `Q`, you can request those three permissions,
>   and you get the same level of access that an app targeting API Level 28 or lower
>   gets from requesting `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` on a Q device. That is still very limited
>   access, only through the `MediaStore`, but it is better than nothing.

Note that this information is current for Q Beta 2, and future beta releases may change the story somewhat.

Comment: They seems to add these permissions again in Android T

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_MEDIA_IMAGES